# Function currying - Scheme

Tags: scheme, factorial, currying

We need to write a currying method that does the same like the procedure below.

```
; Signature: c-bc(n)
; Type: [Number -> [Number -> Number]]
; Purpose: A naive Currying for binomial coefficient (n, k).
; Pre-conditions: n is a natural number
; Tests: ((c-bc 5) 3) => 10, ((c-bc 6) 2) => 15,
; ((c-bc 0) 0) => 1

(define c-bc
  (lambda (n)
    (lambda (k)
      (/ (fact n)
         (* (fact k)
            (fact (- n k)))))))
```

My solution:

```
(define c-bc
  (lambda (n)
    (let ((fact-n (fact n)))
      (lambda (k)
        (/ fact-n (* (fact k) (fact (- n k))))))))
```

Is it right? And how can I explain that this is currying?

Comment: The original function is already currying. I'm not sure what your version is supposed to do differently.

Comment: the first version is currying, but a naive one that compute (fact n) more times than the second solution.
we expected to achieve partial evaluation goals. (as part from uni' course.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is right.  Explain it as: "The binomial coefficient function takes two arguments, n and k.  I've produced a curried function of n returning a function of r that computs the coefficient.  The function of r is 'optimized' because a computation involving only n is lexically bound."